# For $x$ a random real with $-1\leq x \leq1$, what is the probability that $x^2>0.5$?

Tags: probability, geometry

Let x be a random real number where -1$\le$x$\le$1 what is the probability that $x^2$>0.5.
I've tried to use integral to solve it but I'm not sure about it , If there is any book or article would help me to figure out the function to solve any similar problem I'd be pleased.
my solution is :
$$2 \cdot \frac{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}{2} \cdot 
\int_{1/\sqrt 2}^1 (1-x^2)~dx$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show your attempt since that makes it easier for readers to detect any errors you may have made.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: thank for the tutorial, do you think my answer is correct?

Comment: Please check whether I interpreted your expression correctly.

Comment: No it is what I wanted to write,thanks

Comment: Hi! It looks like you computed an expectation, not probability! Check my answer for the correct computation!

Comment: I believe that integral is useful to compute spaces for unpleasant shapes ,please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: also if you support your solution by any book or blog it would be great,thanks for your help and I'm looking forward if you have any general way to solve this kind of problems

Comment: You should specify the distribution. When none is given, it is natural to assume a uniform distribution (like Snared did), but even so, as the asker, you should make it clear. If a non-uniform density is prescribed, then you also need to integrate. With a uniform distribution all you need to do is to calculate the length of the favorable interval(s).

Comment: you're right ,now I understand that it each y has exactly one x I thought it was a shape not curve please excuse me for being stubborn. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^2 = 1/2 \iff x = \pm \sqrt2 / 2$. Due to the shape of $x^2$ near the origin, $x^2 < 1/2$ whenever $x \in [-\sqrt 2 / 2, +\sqrt 2 /  2]$. So that leaves the space for greater being $2(1-\sqrt 2/2)$ by symmetry. Dividing by the total mass of the line segment of length $2$ we get out answer $p(x^2>1/2) = 1-\sqrt 2/2 \approx 0.29$.